# Running the ceylon typechecker from ceylon, like in typechecker/src/main/Main.java

Tags: module, typechecking, ceylon

I'm running the ceylon typechecker from a ceylon project with a run.ceylon which is exactly a ceylon version of typechecker/src/main/Main.java.

This project is supposed to typecheck itself.

It compiles without errors, but at runtime cannot load dependencies for typechecking.

file: source/com/example/withmodule/module.ceylon

```
native("jvm")
module com.example.withmodule "1.0" {
    import com.redhat.ceylon.typechecker "1.3.0" ;
    //import     com.redhat.ceylon.module-resolver "1.3.0";
}
```

file: source/com/example/withmodule/run.ceylon

```
import java.io{File}
import com.redhat.ceylon.cmr.api{RepositoryManager}
import com.redhat.ceylon.cmr.ceylon{CeylonUtils}
import com.redhat.ceylon.compiler.typechecker{TypeCheckerBuilder}
import com.redhat.ceylon.compiler.typechecker.io.cmr.impl{LeakingLogger}

shared void run(){

   value args = ["/absolutepath/ceylon-1.3.0/source/"];


    RepositoryManager repositoryManager = 
            CeylonUtils.repoManager()
                .systemRepo("/absolutepath/ceylon-1.3.0/repo")
                .logger( LeakingLogger())
                .buildManager();

    TypeCheckerBuilder tcb = 
              TypeCheckerBuilder()
                .setRepositoryManager(repositoryManager)
                .verbose(true)
                .statistics(true);

    for (String path in args) {
        tcb.addSrcDirectory( File(path));
    }

    tcb.typeChecker.process();
}
```

It compiles without errors.

But when running it produces errors:

```
error [package not found in imported modules: 'com.redhat.ceylon.cmr.api' (add module import to module descriptor of 'com.example.withmodule')] at 2:7-2:31 of com/example/withmodule/withmodule.ceylon
error [package not found in imported modules: 'com.redhat.ceylon.cmr.ceylon' (add module import to module descriptor of 'com.example.withmodule')] at 3:7-3:34 of com/example/withmodule/withmodule.ceylon
error [package not found in imported modules: 'com.redhat.ceylon.compiler.typechecker' (add module import to module descriptor of 'com.example.withmodule')] at 4:7-4:44 of com/example/withmodule/withmodule.ceylon
error [package not found in imported modules: 'com.redhat.ceylon.compiler.typechecker.io.cmr.impl' (add module import to module descriptor of 'com.example.withmodule')] at 5:7-5:56 of com/example/withmodule/withmodule.ceylon
```

This makes no sense to me, because compilation and typechecking had succeded just before.

It's a fresh ceylon 1.3.0 download, not installed, simply run from the unzipped .tar.gz.

What extra information does the typechecker need that it hadn't got?

Comment: Btw yau, I've just committed some changes for the soon to be released 1.3.1 version where you'll be able to set up a typechecker + model loader in a somewhat simpler way: https://gist.github.com/quintesse/004e33e84553abd75412ceb3d164bf4a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue here is that the typechecker we use in the test runner `typechecker/src/main/Main.java` is only able to understand things defined in Ceylon source code. It is *not* able to read a compiled Java `.jar` archive and typecheck your Ceylon source code against the classes in that archive.

So to be able to typecheck Ceylon code that depends on Java binaries, you would need more infrastructure, including what we call a "model loader" which is responsible for building a Ceylonic model of the Java binary `.class`es. There are a number different model loaders in the Ceylon ecosystem—one for `javac`, one for Eclipse, one for IntelliJ, one that uses Java reflection, one for Dart, one for typescript, one for JS—and they're all very specific to a particular compilation environment.

So the tests for the Ceylon typechecker, which don't depend on `javac`, IntelliJ, Eclipse, etc, etc, don't feature any sort of Java interop. Your code can successfully typecheck things defined in Ceylon source code, including code that depends on Ceylon modules with `.src` archives produced by the Ceylon compiler, but it can't typecheck things defined in a Java `.jar` archive.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, I just learned that getTypeChecker (getter) is rewritten to typeChecker  (attribute). I didn't expect so much industry in that field. Attributes not always comes easily.

Comment: Hi, we had a quick discussion about this and the outcome was that it's probably not a completely straightforward thing to do. You would have to take a look at the source for one of the compilers or IDEs to get an idea of what's involved.